# Connect host ldap server to local VM

Tags: ldap, virtual-machine, opendj

I have a server installed on VM and a LDAP(opendj) server created using Apache Directory Studio on my host computer. Now, I would like to connect that LDAP server to local VM so that the VM server can pull user's information from LDAP server. is it possible to do that? I could not understand how to establish a communication between these two server.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't connect servers. You connect *to* servers, with a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remote Port Forwarding** actually does work here.

my ldap server port was `10389`.
I have created a tunnel from host to vm:

```
ssh -R 10389:localhost:10389 root@172.16.130.132(vm-ip)
```

after then, vm can reach to the host through this port (`10389`).

Sorry, I don't have that much knowledge on ssh. But this one worked for me.